# Import json does not get recognized by Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, import, module

im facing a problem with the code of my webscrawler. Import json does not get recognized by python and i really dont know why.
Psycharm does recognize 'import requests' by color but doesnt recognize 'import json'
The Code works as it should, going through the ISBN.txt, using the corresponding line as the EAN to search for and then printing the price and ISBN out.
But after some results i get following error:

```
C:/Users/Lasse/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py
0.15
9783293003781
0.15
9783423246842
0.15
9783423204545
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lasse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    GetISBN()
  File "C:\Users\Lasse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 17, in GetISBN
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
  File "C:\Python\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone who could help me with that? My Code looks like this:

```
import json
import requests
def GetISBN():
    Lagerbestand = open("ISBN.txt", "r")
    ISBN_Liste = Lagerbestand.read().splitlines()
    i = 0
    while i <= len(ISBN_Liste):
        api_url = "https://api.momox.de/api/v4/offer/"
        params = {"ean": ISBN_Liste[i]}
        headers = {
        "X-API-TOKEN": "2231443b8fb511c7b6a0eb25a62577320bac69b6",
        "X-CLIENT-VERSION": "r5299-76accf6",
        "X-MARKETPLACE-ID": "momox_de",
         }
        data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
        i += 1
        #print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
        if data["price"] != None:
            print(data["price"])
            print(ISBN_Liste[i])
GetISBN()
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting an empty response.

Comment: Do `resp = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers)` then `print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)` and maybe also look at `resp.headers`.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot.. 429 too many requests, when i use `sleep.time()` it runs longer but after some time i get the same error although the timer is already set to 1 sec. is there another option to fix this?

Comment: You need to consult with the API authors. See what your limits are.